# How can I ignore a "redirected" request from the IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, ihttphandler

I have mapped a IHttpHandlerFactory to "all" http requests.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.*" type="HomeController"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

From the home controller, I call different HTTP controllers.

Some of my controllers have to redirect the user to different .aspx files.

Problem: this fires the homecontroller (the factory) again, calling it in an infinite loop.

factory code

```
public class HomeController : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
public HomeController()
{
}


public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
{   ....
        return new HelloWorldHandler2();
    ....
}

public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
{
    if (this.handler.Equals(handler))
    {
        this.handler.busy = false;
    }
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

handler code

```
public class HelloWorldHandler2 : IHttpHandler
{
 public HelloWorldHandler2()
{

}
public bool busy = false;

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
    // This handler is called whenever a file ending 
    // in .sample is requested. A file with that extension
    // does not need to exist.
    //Response.Write("<html>");
    //Response.Write("<body>");
    //Response.Write("<h1>backup handler</h1>" );
    //Response.Write("</body>");
    //Response.Write("</html>");
    context.Handler = this;
    Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
}



public bool IsReusable
{
    // To enable pooling, return true here.
    // This keeps the handler in memory.
    get { return false; }
}
}
```

as you can see, the factory calls the handler, the handler redirects the page, 
the redirection calls the factory again...

Comment: Don not call Response.Redirect("About.aspx") inside ProcessRequest. Use routes

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Thanks Martin! Thanks a lot (I hope admins wouldn't delete this thanks msg).

Comment: John Saunders, you guys really like "ediiting" don't you :). 
Every time I submit a question, the first thing that happen is some admin guy delete a word or two to get his name in the post.
What's wrong with saying thanks to other professionals for spending their time to consider my matter?

I will try not be polite from now on. (if you don't delete my account for questioning your "authority")

I CHALLENGE you to keep this comment and respond to this as a pro.